# multidex requires build tools 21.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio

приложение уровня "hello, world"

только, что запускалось

сделал `Rebuild Project`

вылезла ошибка `multidex requires build tools 21.0.0 / Current: 19.1`

как отключить обновление?

зачем HelloWorld нужно обновить библиотеки?

Comment: Видимо вы используете compileSDKversion 21

Comment: а почему только, что работало? настройки: `compileSdkVersion 23`  `buildToolsVersion "19.1.0" `  `minSdkVersion 19`

Comment: в данном случае 21.0.0 это версия инструментов сборки проектов. По идее она напрямую не связана с  compileSDKversion

Comment: а как настроить так чтоб HelloWorld запускалось на текущих версиях?

Comment: @ZigZag Дело в том, что в BuildTools 21.0.0 [была добавлена поддержка](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html?hl=ru) Android 5.0 (API21) .

Answer (score 2):

Об обновлении говорит не ваше приложение а сама студия. Обновите инструменты сборки при помощи Android SDK Manager. На текущий момент актуальной является версия 23.0.3 от марта 2016г. Она и должна поддержать выбранный Вами compileSdkVersion 23.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, дело в том, что в BuildTools 21.0.0 [была добавлена поддержка](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html?hl=ru) Android 5.0 (API21), а вы используете compileSDKversion 23 (хотя тогда бы, наверное, build tools 23 запросила бы) или возможно какие то классы из этого API.

Либо установите compileSDKversion < 21, либо (что предпочтительнее) обновите Build Tools (и другие инструменты) до актуальных версий через SDK Manager. Хотя может придется ограничить и maxSDKversion = 20, я просто никогда не задавался целью ограничить API сверху, как и пытаться запустить что то на неактуальных инструментах, поэтому с уверенностью сказать не могу, что надо сделать.

Обновления инструментов требует не приложение, а система сборки (IDE), так как ей, по всей видимости, нужны возможности этих обновленных инструментов, чтобы собрать проект с вашими настойками сборки.